# Biconditional elimination and implication elimination rules canceling statement out?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, artificial-intelligence

I'm learning about propositional logic and converting statements to conjunctive normal form. If I have a statement such as $t \leftrightarrow q$, a biconditional statement,
and I apply apply biconditional elimination to get:

$$(t \to q) \land (q \to t)$$

Then through implication elimination I get:

$$(\neg t \lor q) \land (\neg q \lor t)$$

Would I be able to eliminate both $t$ and $q$? I have $\neg t$ and $t$, which would cancel out, and same with $q$ and $\neg q$. How can I simplify this last statement further?

Comment: If you are working with Resolution, the formula amounts to a pair of clauses: $\{ ¬t∨q \}, \{  ¬q∨t \}$. Resolving with $t$ (the choice is immaterial) what you get will be $¬q∨q$ which is a tautology.

Comment: But this is a post about converting to CNF, not about determining satisfiability (via resolution or other means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literals you mention are in different clauses of the formula, hence they cannot be eliminated; at no point is there a conjunction of the form $a \land \neg a (\equiv 0)$ or a disjunction of the form $a \lor \neg a (\equiv 1)$.

Also, your formula cannot be simplified any further.
If you were to "simplify" one of the clauses (if you simplified both, the resulting formula would only have 1 satisfying assignment while your original one had 2) by somehow replacing it with a literal, the resulting formula would be monotone (while the original one is not) and if you got rid of one of the clauses entirely the resulting formula could be satisfied by only setting one of the variables to some value and not caring about the other one (which is in contrast to the original formula which can only be satisfied by setting $t$ and $q$ to the same value).

Comment: i think your statement a little bit wrong.You said "Also, your formula cannot be simplified any further".This statement can give rise to some misunderstoods in the future for this user.For example ;if it is being made a proof,this logical satatement can be simplified by conjuction elimination.I am not saying your answer wrong but it is a little dangerous for beginners..Thank for your contributions

Comment: It is not wrong though. The post is about converting a given formula to CNF and OP wondered whether there is a "simpler" CNF formula which is still equivalent to the original one. I argued that this is not the case, providing reasons for why there are no "simpler" such CNF formulas with the desired properties. Of course this is subject to a definition of "simpler", but I think I covered the most common one (smaller clauses, fewer clauses).